# can orbitdb be used as key-value store backend for datalog database? like datahike?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, datalog, orbitdb

- orbitdb has docs store - but this querying is too low level
- there is aviondb - but mongo querying is also lower level than SQL or datalog

can orbitdb be used as a key-value store for a high-level datalog database? like datahike?

Answer (score 0):

- Arthur-Dent - datahike on nodejs - now has working orbitdb backend as alternative to indexeddb
- code is salvaged from broken-by-authors 206-cljs-support branch of datahike

  - orbitdb key-value store https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Arthur-Dent/blob/8e6087a58895c23424e89da46a7a8e61c1318dc3/konserve/src/konserve/orbitdb.cljs
  - Fennec program runs him https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Fennec/blob/ae7eb4ffcaed2ab93648d34a5e1a0a27f6484e40/src/Fennec/beans.cljs#L49